# Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start". for Landsat 8 T1_SR

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, timestamp

It's weird, when I run the attached code on Landsat8 TOA band it works fine. But when I switch out the bands to the SR band I get the message below:

Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start".

I found some suggestions about .copyProperties(image[system:time_start]) and tried putting it in a few different spots, but couldn't figure it out.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e7fb97a366c97723ce0c82675125816d

Answer (score 0):

Issue is produced because you don't have a time series. You only have an image (bare) without 'system:time_start'. I introduced an arbitrary 'system:time_start' (ee.Date('2014-09-01')) in that image ([code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d8e7fc7ff96399106873ab2836a03fd9)) and it can be corroborated there is no series for producing an useful chart (see following image).

[image]

So, you need a time series from your Image Collection named **dataset**. I modified your code only for producing a chart with NDVI, NDWI and bare time series (you need to think in a new area calculation because there are many different images in bare series). I named it as **new_dataset**.

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA"),
    study_area = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-117.84500295847182, 47.075614857150875],
          [-117.84500295847182, 46.857254580115004],
          [-117.25174123972182, 46.857254580115004],
          [-117.25174123972182, 47.075614857150875]]], null, false);

Map.addLayer(study_area, {color: 'Black'}, "study_area");
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image input Landsat 8 SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloudmasked Landsat 8 image
 */
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.clip(study_area)
    .updateMask(mask);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2014-09-01', '2015-11-30')
                  .filterBounds(study_area)
                  .map(maskL8sr)
                  .select('B5' , 'B4', 'B3');
print(dataset);

var dataset = dataset.map(function calcIndices (img){
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'); // NDVI calculated using NIR and red bands
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI'); // NDVI calculated using NIR and red bands
  
  var time = img.get('system:time_start');
  
  // Create a binary layer using logical operations.
  var bare = ndvi.lt(0.2).and(ndwi.lt(0)).rename('bare')
   .set('system:time_start', time);
  
  return img.addBands([ndvi, ndwi, bare]);
});

var new_dataset = dataset.map (function selectBands(img){
  
  return img.select(['NDVI', 'NDWI', 'bare']);
  
});

print(new_dataset);

print(ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: new_dataset,
  region: study_area,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 30,
}).setOptions({title: 'Cloud-masked Bare Soil over time',

}));
```

After running [above code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/950f9233e450587e629033038f442d1e) in GEE code editor, result was as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! Something is wrong with the bare variable. It shouldn't bolt up and down like it is. Not quite sure why it is doing this. Bare soil should be smoother like NDVI and NDWI as the bare variable is produce from them